# Некорректная запись в xml файл

Tags: python, xml

При добавлении в уже существующий xml файл нескольких элементов в цикле, они идут подряд, без переноса строк, сплошным текстом.

```
temp = ET.SubElement(sub_item, 'ElementName')
temp.text = sometext
```

Comment: Стандарт формата не предусматривает никаких переводов строк, это игнорируемый элемент. Нужен - добавляй вручную.

Comment: А я разве не делаю это вручную?

Comment: Неа, вы добавляете новый элемент в структуру, а потом при сохранении эта структура сериализуется в текст в формате xml, вот вам как раз и хочется в тот текст добавить переводы строк, Кст, это называют как `pretty xml`

Comment: xstr = ET.tostring(temp, encoding = 'UTF-8', method = 'xml') + '\n'.encode('ascii')                                                                                             
temp = ET.fromstring(xstr)
Должно работать по идее, но почему-то все равно строка не переносится